# Perl script to automate a website for bioinformatics

Tags: perl, web

I would like to automate this website with a Perl script

http://bioinfo.uni-plovdiv.bg/microinspector/

This is what I have so far and I am not sure how to get to the output page after this, I know it has something to do with POST, redirect_ok?, response(), but I am not sure. I read through the documentation but am confused about some things. Thanks.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;

# create object for browser
my $browser = WWW::Mechanize->new();
my ($sequence, $results);
open (DRG, "<microRNA_target_cspg_drg_output.fa") || die "cannot open microRNA_target_cspg_drg_output.fa";

while (<DRG>) {
        chomp;
        $sequence=$_;
        last; #for testing purposes
}
close (DRG);

$browser->get("http://bioinfo.uni-plovdiv.bg/microinspector/");
$browser->form_number(1);
$browser->field("target_sequence", $sequence);
$browser->field("Choose an organism : ", "Mus musculus");
$browser->click_button( number => 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should start with [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/). It's page provides examples on submitting forms, and anything else you will need.

EDIT: as a reply to your update, if you want to get the content of the page, use the `content` method, like in this example:

```
my $content = $browser->content();
```

See [this](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/WWW-Mechanize-1.66/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#%24mech-%3Econtent%28...%29) for more info.

Comment: Hi Geo, I am still having trouble after reading the thing you suggested and trying it. I have a few questions. After I do 'click_button' does the page submit or do I need to do something for that to happen. Another webpage pops up when you click search on the website; I didn't phrase my question right from before, I was wondering how I get to that new page. Sorry for all these questions but this is completely new to me. Thanks.

Comment: Another question I have is for form_number(n), if I have form_number(1) and form_number(2) does that mean it's two separate instances of the forms or is form_number(2) the output of form_number(1) after you click/submit form 1? Thanks

Comment: Hey! Yes, when you `click`, the form gets submitted. But, if another page opens up, why don't you open that page directly? Instead of going to the starting page, and then to your search page. You could even post directly to your search form, and you could set the referer to point to the starting page. And for the `form_number`, it actually represents a form in the page. For example, `form_number(3)` would select the 3rd form in the current page.